# How to make Wanderlust mark replied emails as "answered"

Tags: email, wanderlust

I noticed that Wanderlust 2.15.9 (Almost Unreal) does not automatically mark an email as "answered" to which I have written a reply, as some other mail clients do.  How can I make it do so?  I am aware that there are `wl-summary-mark-as-answered` and the likes, but I am not sure how to use them from a elisp code.

Comment: I use `wl-summary-reply-with-citation` and mine gets marked as "`a`" with the whole line is `wl-highlight-summary-answered-face`, but I don't know if I previously fixed it to mark the email as answered (it has been several years already).  What function are you using to answer?  I'm happy to trace, but would like to make sure I'm starting with the right function.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you for your attention!  I use `mime-preview-follow-current-entity` in an MIME-View-mode buffer, since oftentimes I want to cite only the text/plain part of the email.  And you are right, if I use your function the message gets marked as answered.

Comment: Rather than getting fancy with advice, I would probably just create a new function:  `(defun foo () (interactive) (wl-summary-mark-as-answered) (mime-preview-follow-currentity))`  I looked at the function you are calling and I didn't see any hooks that were obvious.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you for your help.  Ideally, I'd like to mark the message as answered only after sending the reply, since I often start writing a reply without completing it...

Comment: What function do you use to send the email after replying with `mime-preview-follow-current-entity`?

Comment: @lawlist `wl-draft-send-and-exit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is based on a bare-bones default configuration, with the following three steps:

1. From the `Summary` buffer, select a message with the space bar (aka `wl-summary-read`).
2. From the `" *WL:Message*"` buffer, type `M-x mime-preview-follow-current-entity`.
3. From the `"+draft/1"` buffer, press `C-c C-c` (aka `wl-draft-send-and-exit`).

**CAVEAT**:  The default value for `mime-preview-following-method-alist` is `((wl-original-message-mode . wl-message-follow-current-entity))`.

```lisp
(require 'wl)

(defun wl-message-follow-current-entity (buffer)
  "Follow to current message.  @lawlist redefined this function so that
`wl-draft-reply' uses the optional argument of NUMBER.  NUMBER will become
`wl-draft-parent-number' by virtue of `wl-draft-create-buffer'."
  (wl-draft-reply  ;; reply to all
    (wl-message-get-original-buffer)
    nil
    wl-message-buffer-cur-summary-buffer
    wl-message-buffer-cur-number)
  (let ((mail-reply-buffer buffer))
    (wl-draft-yank-from-mail-reply-buffer nil)))
```

Comment: I put your code in my `.wl`, but it didn't mark the message as answered.  Perhaps this has to do with lexical/dynamic binding?  (My Emacs version is 24.4.1.)

Comment: In the comments underneath the original question, you indicated that the buffer is in `mime-view-mode`.  The default configuration when following steps 1, 2 and 3 above will result in a `wl-draft-mode` buffer.  So, we need to backtrack to see what actual steps are you taking beginning from the Summary buffer to end up with a `mime-view-mode` buffer after launching `M-x mime-preview-follow-current-entity`.  We should also check the value of `mime-preview-following-method-alist` to see whether you have modified the default setting `((wl-original-message-mode . wl-message-follow-current-entity))`

Comment: As it turns out, your code works now.  I believe what I was experiencing was due to some inconsistency in defuns or lack of synchronization between Wanderlust and the IMAP server.  Thank you!

Comment: I was able to simply everything down to just adding an optional argument to `wl-draft-reply` within `wl-message-follow-current-entity`.  The previous fix to `wl-draft-send` relating to using the `mail-send-actions` is a bonafide fix, but is not needed for this answer.